# Método setActivated() onBindViewHolder()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

He estado leyendo la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview-custom?hl=es-419) de android y he visto que mediante la implementación del método `setActivated()` en el `onBindHolder` de un `RecyvlerView` se pueden dar por ejemplo, valores iniciales a los elementos de un `girdLayout`, como el color de una celda en concreto en función de una variable de la activity.

He estado buscando por internet y no encuentro ningún repositorio de código al respecto y no sé cómo implementarlo.

¿Alguien puede guiarme?

Gracias

En el onBind con este código si me marca bien las personas ocupadas:

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Basico.RecyclerViewHolders> {
private List itemList;
private Context context;

```
        public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
            this.itemList = itemList;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Basico.RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
            Basico.RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new Basico.RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
            return rcv;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MBasico.RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
            holder.ocupado.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
            holder.foto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());

                switch (position)
                {

                    case 0:
                        if (p.getOcupado()==1)
                        {
                            holder.fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
                            holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                        }
                        break;
                    
                }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return this.itemList.size();
        }

    }
```

Pero en el onclick no me detecta bien si está ocupado o no, siempre empieza con pulsado =0 y luego pasa a 1, independientemente del valor devuelto por getOcupado().

public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

```
        public TextView name;
        public ImageView foto;
        public RelativeLayout fondo;

        public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            foto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
            fondo = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fondo_item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                switch (getAdapterPosition())
                {
                    case 0:
                        if (p.getOcupado()==1)
                        {
                           pulsado=1;
                        }
                        break;
                }


            if (pulsado == 0) {
                pulsado = 1;
                fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
                name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

                switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        p.setOcupado(1);
                        break;

            } else {
                pulsado = 0;
                fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));

                switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        p.setOcupado(0);
                        break;
                  
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un array de int global.

```
 int[] ocupados = new int[n];
```

En este array pondrás el 0 o el 1 en función de si está ocupado o no (tiene uno el objeto en la variable). N será el número de items.

En el `onCreate()` de la activity deberás dar valores a este vector en función de lo que recibas:

```
if (p.getOcupado()==1)
 {
     ocupados[0]=1;
 }
else
{
     ocupados[0]=;
```

En tu método onBind puedes hacer esto:

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Basico.RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
           name.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
           foto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());

                switch (position)
                {

                    case 0:
                        if (p.getOcupado()==1)
                        {
                               holder.fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                               name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                        }
                        break;

....
```

y en el `onCLick()` deberás consultar el array ocupados para saber si tiene 1 o 0:

```
 if (ocupados[getAdapterPosition()] == 0) {
                ocupados[getAdapterPosition()]=1;
                fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

                switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        p.setOcupado(1);
                        break;
              }

} else {
                ocupados[getAdapterPosition()]=0;
                fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        p.setOcupado(0);
                        break;
}
```